# Upon upgrade to Rails 6.1 my postgres database is no longer accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm addressing some vulnerabilities that were identified by one of our automated systems. Basically, it just recommends dependency updates to mitigate CVE vulns. As a result, I had to upgrade Rails from 6.05 to 6.1.7. Also, the `pg` gem was updated from 0.21.0 to 1.1. Locally everything works fine. I can run my tests, everything passes, etc. Our continuous integration system is where the problem happens. I can kick off a build with our master branch and everything works, but when I try to build my branch with the 6.1 upgrade, I get the following error...

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/config/application_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError:
  FATAL:  database "appname_test" does not exist
```

I confirmed the database does in fact exist, and as I mentioned, other branches build without issue using the same database. There were no changes to the database config. It doesn't really contain much besides the `url` key which just uses the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Is there something with Rails 6.1 or pg 1.1 that changes how a database url is used in the test environment?

Comment: I could suggest to update gems separately to detect exactly which of two has the reason of problem. Also PG server version and format of DATABASE_URL env (w/o password!) would be helpful.

Comment: It's not lying. It doesn't exist *at least as you've configured it*. I'd check that some other setting hasn't changed, like it's not defaulting to SQLite or something in your build environment.